# Add new referenced entity if none was found using Inline Entity Form autocomplete

Tags: ajax, entities

Is there any module or other solution for Drupal 7, that would extend Inline Entity Form to offer creation of new entity if none was found using autocomplete widget? Yes, I can cancel the form and create new entity, but this isn't straightforward. I also found some discussions about this, but no solution integrated with IEF:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autocreate
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1540944

Does anything like this exist?